# NUnit 'Assert' does not contain a definition for 'Multiple'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, nunit

I have started hooking up NUnit to my Unity project using C#/Visual Studio/etc. when I came across a brick wall. Based on [the documentation](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Multiple-Asserts), I should have access to a Multiple Assert function. I wrote a test that looks like this:

```
[Test]
public void Ease_TypeFall_WillMiddleCorrect() {
    Vector3 value = Calcu.Ease (Calcu.EaseType.Fall, StartVector, EndVector, .5f, 1f);
    Assert.Multiple (() => {
        Assert.AreEqual (value.x, 6.24264f, .0001f);
        Assert.AreEqual (value.y, 6.24264f, .0001f);
        Assert.AreEqual (value.z, 6.24264f, .0001f);
    });
}
```

I am getting an error on `Assert.Multiple` that looks like this:

```
'Assert' does not contain a definition for 'Multiple'
```

I installed NUnit through the NuGet package manager, from what I can tell, I have the latest version installed and All portions of it. After some Googling, I haven't seen anyone with a similar issue to mine.

I can obviously split this into 3 asserts, but it would really be nice to know what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: When you hover over `Assert` what namespace does it show? Have you tried doing a clean and rebuild? Could be an old dll hanging around.

Comment: Unrelated tip: your parameters to `Assert.AreEqual` are the wrong way around. The first parameter should be the `expected` value, the second should be the `actual` value. (As it stands the message when the assertion fails will be misleading.) You may prefer the more logical approach offered by the constraint-based assertion syntax: `Assert.That(actual, Is.EqualTo(expected));` or `Assert.That(actual, Is.EqualTo(expected).Within(tolerance));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unity provides a modified version of the nunit framework, which unfortunately has the same name as the standard nunit framework. It's a known issue of theirs that Assert.Multiple is not yet supported.

Comment: Dang, I was afraid of something like that. At least I'm not crazy.

Comment: Is this still correct/true?

Comment: According to [this page](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.test-framework@1.1/manual/index.html) Unity is based on version 3.5 of NUnit (October, 2016), although they reference the latest NUnit documentation. `Assert.Multiple` was not introduced until NUnit 3.6. The above page lists the missing features under "Limitations" but this is still in reference to NUnit 3.5 and doesn't include lots of features, which NUnit introduced from 2016 onward.